# What happened between Kirito and Asuna in those 2 years?

Tags: sword-art-online

According to the 2nd episode, Kirito and Asuna met in the first month of SAO. Yet 2 years later, they meet again and it seems they are like complete strangers.

What happened to them in those 2 years? Do the light novels explain this?

Comment: "Yet, 2 years later, they meet again and it seems they are like complete strangers." - Where is this mentioned? I don't remember this at all.

Comment: Same, they were constantly together on the clearing groups and they killed the first boss together too. He was also constantly running into here, IIRC.

Comment: Its a world of -10k people.  They probably were bound to meet each other.  "It's a small world after all"

Comment: Sword Art Online: Progressive

Comment: This is where the glopping noise of 2 years worth of  ****** comes into play, right?

Answer (score 12):

During the two years, players teamed up to clear the floors.  However Kirito decided to solo the game (heavily influenced by Sachi's death ep. 3).  This made contact between other players uncommon.  Even though Kirito was a solo player, he participated in Boss Battles.

Before the boss battles he talked with other players for strategy. Asuna being one of the leaders, and Kirito being one of the strongest of players, would talk to each other or at least be in the same area.

It was referenced during the time of Gleam Eyes (Boss of the 74th Floor) when Klein found Kirito in a party with Asuna.

Answer (score 8):

In the anime, a *lot* happens to Kirito through those two years.

- He distances himself from other players after clearing the first floor's boss, due to him being identified as a "Beater" (beta tester/cheater).  When he does run into people he knows from the real world...

  > ...he reluctantly agrees to join a guild with them, then they go on a raid and it winds up costing all of his friends their lives.  He shoulders that grief for the next two years.
- He tells Asuna to go ahead and join a guild if she sees an opportunity, due to her strength.
- He never really got to *know* her in the short period of time they interacted when clearing that boss, except for the fact that this was her first MMO, and that she was surprisingly talented.

Two years later, they reunite - recognizing each other from the boss raid they did way back when.  That's about all they could recognize each other from, anyway.  In that time, they've both become very strong SAO players, and are fighting on the front lines, determined to clear the game.

Comment: Progressive doesn't agree with you. It seems Kirito and Asuna were together up until 9th floor. Eg. where beta testers were able to get.

Comment: I was following the progression of the anime, as that's the only real reference material I have at hand.

Answer (score 1):

They both meet at a guild, trying to beat the first level, and they formed a group. Kirito becomes a solo player, then plays in a guild called “The Moonlit Black Cats”. They then meet again, and sort of like each other. Asuna wants to quit the “Knights of the Blood Oath” but Heathcliff stops them. Kirito challenges him, and the leader turns out to be Akahiko Kayaba (the creator of SAO). As a result, Kirito try’s to stab him, but Heathcliff prevents himself from dying with an immortal shield. Kirito then has a fight with Heathcliff. Then, Kirito gets almost killed before Asuna comes to save him and dies instead. Kirito says he wants to be here for sleeping today.

Answer (score -3):

Ok, so kirito first met asuna while clearing the first floor. They team up, and beat the boss. They later meet while buying bread and after that when kirito is sleeping and the whole grimlock thing happens. That basically is what happens in the two years.